# how to get fibonacci series within range without recursion

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am trying to calculate the fibonacci numbers within specific range(wide range of numbers in thousands) 
I have wrote this but for I do not know to to modify it to make it within a range for example i need to get fibonacci numbers between 5027 and 8386589

```
class Fibonacci
{  
  public static void main(String args[])  
  {    
    int n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count=10;    
    System.out.print(n1+" "+n2);//printing 0 and 1    

    for(i=2;i<count;++i)    
    {    
      n3=n1+n2;    
      System.out.print(" "+n3);    
      n1=n2;    
      n2=n3;    
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: 5027 and 8386589 are not a fibonacci numbers, so you want the range to be between 2 given normal numbers, yes?

Comment: If you want to perform Fibonacci between a range of values and want to avoid to start from 1... you need at least the first two values for the sequence, otherwise you won't able to get the next value.

Comment: What are you trying to get out of it? Just print the numbers in the given range? Or get a List of the numbers that are in the range? Or count them? Or what?

Comment: @araknoid no i just want to start normal but i want to get all numbers between certain range

Comment: @Ray No I want to get them and then I will apply some operation on these numbers like summing them etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int fib(int low, int high){
       // Initialize first three Fibonacci Numbers
       int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3 = 1;

       // Count fibonacci numbers in given range
       int result = 0;

       while (n1 <= high){
            if (n1 >= low)
               result++;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            f3 = f1 + f2;
        }

        return result;
 }
```

Comment: This counts the number of fibonacci numbers in the range; is that what OP wants? "i need to get fibonacci numbers between 5027 and 8386589" is a little unclear.

Comment: At least that's what i understood :') @Ray.

Comment: Thanks for you that helped me so much

Comment: @Rania Saeed لا شكر على واجب

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop instead of a for loop and include an if-statement

```
while(n3<8386589){
 if(n3>5027){
    System.out.print(n3+" ");    
 }
 n3=n1+n2;    
 n1=n2;    
 n2=n3; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's my version (also using a `while` loop):

```
private static void Fibonacci(long lower, long upper)
    {
        long curr = 1, prev = 1;

        while (curr <= upper)
        {
            long temp = curr;

            curr = prev + curr;

            prev = temp;

            if (curr >= lower && curr <= upper)
            {
                System.out.println(curr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts I understand it clearly now

Answer (score 0):

The some idea just using BigInteger for bigger values :

```
private static BigInteger function_f(int n) {

    // if n = 0 => f(n) = 0
    if(n == 0) 
        return new BigInteger("0");

    // Initialization of variables
    // if n = 1 => f(n) = 1 (case included)
    BigInteger  result = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger  last_fn = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger  before_last_fn = new BigInteger("0");

    // Do the loop for n > 1
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {

        // f(n - 2)
        before_last_fn = last_fn;
        // f(n - 1)
        last_fn = result;
        // f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
        result = last_fn.add(before_last_fn);

    }

    // Return the result
    return result;      
}
```